# Redirecting URLs (with specific GET parameters)

Tags: apache, http, redirect

I have this old survey link that is has been superseded by another link, so basically I want anyone trying to access the URL:

http://mywebsite.com/survey/view_survey.php?surveyID=1

To be redirected to:

http://mywebsite.com/survey/view_survey.php?surveyID=2

Can I do this in the Apache configuration or htaccess file?

I tried the following rule in the Redirect section of my httpd.conf file:

```
Redirect 301 /survey/view_survey.php?surveyID=1 http://mywebsite.com/survey/view_survey.php?surveyID=2
```

But it doesn't work. I am suspecting that the GET parameters are not used when processing the rule.

Is my only option to hack my code to redirect on a specific surveyID?

---

Following the suggestion of using the Rewrite rules, I tried the following in my .htaccess file:

```
RewriteRule ^survey/view_survey\.php\?surveyID=1525$ /survey/view_survey.php?sur
veyID=1607
```

But that doesn't work. I do have the rewrite engine up and running, because I have another rewrite rule currently running.

Comment: For my own knowledge, why is getting the .htaccess file going easier than a line of php?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try this in a .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|.*&)surveyID=1525(&.*|$)
RewriteRule ^survey/view_survey\.php$ /survey/view_survey.php?%1surveyID=1607%2 [L,R=301]
```

Comment: Didn't work out. I got into a loop.

URL was /survey/view_survey.php?surveyID=1607&surveyID=1607(.. repeated a bunch of times)&surveyID=1525

FireFox gave me the error:

Redirect Loop
Firefox has detected that the server is redirecting the request for this address in a way that will never complete.

Comment: It seems that the QSA flag causes this behavior.

Answer (score 2):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^surveyID=1525$
RewriteRule ^/survey/view_survey\.php /survey/view_survey.php?surveyID=1607 [R=301]
```

Answer (score 0):

Check out the QSA portion of the mod_rewrite.

It does GET string manipulation.

Comment: QSA won't help here because it's the match pattern that's wrong

Answer (score 0):

There might be a possible duplicate of this question and it is solved if this solution doesnt work for you:

[Apache Redirect 301 fails when using GET parameters, such as ?blah=](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1260632/apache-redirect-301-fails-when-using-get-parameters-such-as-blah)