# How to rewrite urls using htaccess?

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting

Using htaccess how to turn this type of URL:

```
http://www.mysite.com/page.php?slug=hello-world
```

into this type:

```
http://www.mysite.com/page/hello-world
```

And not just this one url but all urls in the 1st format to the 2nd format.

Answer (score 3):

If the second one is the URL you want people to see, use this:

```
RewriteRule ^page/(.*)$ /page.php?slug=$1
```

If it's the other way around:

```
RewriteRule ^page\.php?slug=(.*)$ /page/$1
```

---

EDIT: Also, make sure you have the following in your `.htaccess` before ANY RewriteRules:

```
RewriteEngine On
```

Comment: this isn't working for me, I put the 1st block of code you posted in a .htaccess file which I placed at the root of my www folder. Then I tried to access the page by typing http://www.mysite.com/page/hello-world and it didn't work.

Comment: Yes I added the rewrite engine on declaration, still it returns a 404 page not found error :(

Comment: I just tried this and it worked fine. Are any redirects working for you? mod_rewrite enabled, .htaccess not ignored?

Answer (score 1):

You may want to refer to [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/583705/redirecting-urls-with-specific-get-parameters) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1260632/apache-redirect-301-fails-when-using-get-parameters-such-as-blah)

Here is my thought to your solution:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^slug=[^/]+$ [NC] 
RewriteRule ^page\.php$ http://www.mysite.com/page/$1? [R=301,L]
```

Comment: What this code does is redirect me to mysite.com/product when I type mysite.com/product.php?slug=hello-world which of course is a not found. And if I type mysite.com/page/hello-world it too results in a 404.

Comment: could you specify your question more? the word 'turn' is not clear, do you mean frontend redirect / server redirect? and it is better to state what parameters in the url you want to change...