# HTTP redirect one URL to another based on query string

Tags: php, apache, redirect, http-status-code-301, mod-alias

When the URL **`/page1.php?abc`** is requested, I want it redirected to **`/page1.php?xyz`** instead.

Specifically, this is what I want to tell the client:

```
HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
Location: /page1.php?xyz
```

I've tried Apache [RedirectMatch](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_alias.html#redirectmatch) directive, but it doesn't seem to support query strings.

Is there another directive which supports HTTP-redirect for URLs with query strings?

Currently I'm accomplishing this using [PHP's header function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php), but this feels like a stopgap hack so I'm looking for an Apache solution.

Comment: [Redirecting URLs (with specific GET parameters)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/583705/redirecting-urls-with-specific-get-parameters?rq=1)?

Comment: @peterm, the accepted solution in that page doesn't work. Basically it rewrites the page, without sending 301 redirects to the client. It's a *totally* different thing.

Comment: Does [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1260632/apache-redirect-301-fails-when-using-get-parameters-such-as-blah) address your problem?

Comment: @Barmar, nope it is the same as the above. They are saying to use mod_rewrite (client will do 1 HTTP request) as a *workaround*, but  it is a totally different thing from using HTTP redirect (client will do 2 HTTP requests, future requests will request the new URL instead of the old one)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `mod_rewrite` for this. If this module is available you use these rules (must be placed inside `/.htaccess`):

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ="abc"
RewriteRule ^page1\.php$ /page1.php?xyz [R=301,L]
```

There is a PHP-only solution too:

```
if ($_SERVER["QUERY_STRING"] == "abc") {
    header("Location: /page1.php?xyz", true, 301);
    die;
}
```

Comment: What makes you say that RewriteEngine is not capable of sending redirect headers? The `R` flag does exactly what you want.

Answer (score 0):

I would create a PHP file that would generate one itself, don't know about a Apache module/solution that could do this.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php

Comment: I guess you posted this answer before he updated his question to say that this is what he's currently doing.