# Redirecting a specific url with parameters

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect

I want to redirect

http://www.mountainfoxinn.com/forum/showthread.php?t=33105&p=246263

to

http://www.mountainfoxinn.com/forum/

through .htaccess file in document root. I have RewriteEngine On and some simpler redirections are working. But this one is not working. I have tried following rules but none of them are working.

```
1. RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^p=246263$
   RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://mountainfoxinn/forum? [R=301,L]

2. RewriteRule ^(.)showthread.php(.)$ http://mountainfoxinn/forum/ [L,R=301]

3. RewriteRule ^(.)246263(.)$ http://mountainfoxinn/forum/ [L,R=301]
```

Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: So you want to redirect from a specific thread to the forum home page? To what end?

Comment: Looks like what you want http://stackoverflow.com/questions/583705/redirecting-urls-with-specific-get-parameters

Comment: @user2922822: Do you have `.htaccess` in forum directory? If yes then post your code here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first rule was almost right. `^` at the beginning of a regex will match the beginning of the string and similary `$` at the end of a regex will match the end. You'll need to match the entire query string (`^t=33105&p=246263$`) or `p=246263` somewhere in that string.

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^t=33105&p=246263$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.reefland.com/forum? [R,L]
```

or

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} p=246263
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.reefland.com/forum? [R,L]
```

Comment: +1 Good answer. To the point. I would suggest no capture and using `R=301` though.

Comment: @sumurai8 No, both of your rules are not working. :(

Comment: @user2922822 How doesn't it work? Doesn't it redirect? Doesn't it redirect to the right place? Does it display the wrong thing? Are you sure mod_rewrite is installed and enabled?

Comment: yes, rewrite is enabled, as other redirects are working. after applying this rule, the http://www.mountainfoxinn.com/forum/showthread.php?t=33105&p=246263 is simply opening.

Comment: Well, that hostname doesn't resolve to an ip, so obviously it won't work.

Comment: No, no, the site is working, I have just not given the actual name of my site, for obvious reasons