# Need to redirect GET-Params exists or value is greater than x

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, typo3

In an older TYPO3 project, content was integrated into a page tree with mount points.

Meanwhile I integrate the content based on the content elements. Unfortunately the old URLs are still called by SEMrush, Bing and Google, although they are no longer linked anywhere.

Now I have to forward all URLs containing the GET parameter "MP" to the start page or the 404 error page.

SEMrush also queries URLs that have a five-digit language ID, although only 4 languages have been defined. The whole thing already borders on link spam. So I would also have to catch and redirect the URLs with the parameter "L" greater than 4.

Currently the called URLs look like this:
https://www.example.com/index.php?id=200&L=42121121121212.1&MP=17-219

Answer (score 0):

If I understand it correctly.

Something like this could help you.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !(^|.*&)L=\d{1-4}(&.*|$)
RewriteRule ^/404.html [L,R=404]
```

Heavily inspired by:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/583805/1210799

Comment: Please excuse my late reaction.  Unfortunately I could not solve it in various ways, because also spaces and special characters were passed.  The bots were not exclusively from Semrush and I was able to ensure silence by blocking IP areas.  Thanks for your time.