# Redirect (301 or 302) for translated page not working

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, translation, multilingual

I want to redirect a translated page to another translated page in the htaccess file.
In the original language it works (`Redirect 301 /helpie_faq/what-are-my-benefits/ /faq/#hfaq-post-1683`), but the redirection of translated pages doesn't work, e.g.

```
Redirect 301 /helpie_faq/welche-vorteile-erhalte-ich-als-neueinwanderer/?lang=de /faq/?lang=de#hfaq-post-3001
```

How can I make this work out?

Answer (score 1):

You need to match on the query string, which the redirect directive does not support. Instead you should use RewriteCond on the URI (REQUEST_URI) and on the query string (QUERY_STRING) and a matching RewriteRule.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /helpie_faq/welche-vorteile-erhalte-ich-als-neueinwanderer$
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^lang=de$
RewriteRule ^.*$ /faq/?lang=de#hfaq-post-3001 [L,R=301]
```

For more examples look here [Apache Redirect 301 fails when using GET parameters, such as ?blah=](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1260632/apache-redirect-301-fails-when-using-get-parameters-such-as-blah) or here [Redirecting URLs (with specific GET parameters)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/583705/redirecting-urls-with-specific-get-parameters)

Comment: A link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: [add context around the link](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you're linking to in case the target page is unavailable. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted](https://stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers).